# On different versions of the Levy-Khinchin formula

Tags: probability-theory

I have a question that is not so much technical in nature, but more about the historical development of the topic of infinitely divisible distributions.

In older but highly reputable probability textbook one finds the following representation if $\phi(t) $ is the ch.functions of $X $ where $X $ has an infinitely divisible law, then
$$ \phi(t) = \exp\biggl\{i\gamma t +\int_R \biggl(e^{itx}-1 -\frac{itx}{1+x^2}\biggl)\cdot \frac{1+x^2}{x^2}\, G(dx)\biggl\} $$
where $\gamma \in R $ and $G $ is a bounded non-decreasing function such that
$G(-\infty) = 0. $ In particular, if $G $ is taken as left-continuous, the representation is unique. \
In more modern textbooks, on the other hand, we often find something like

$$ \phi(t) = \exp\biggl\{i\gamma t -\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t^2 +\int_R \biggl(e^{itx}-1 -it1_{|x|<1}(x)\biggl)\, \nu(dx)\biggl\} $$
where $\nu $ is a $\sigma-$finite (it is easy to prove) measure such that
$ \int_R (1\wedge x^2)\, \nu(dx) < \infty $ or some similar condition such as
$\int \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\, \nu(dx) < \infty. $

The functions that appear inside the brackets could be different and will only determine a change of the parameter $\gamma $ in either representation.

My specific question is: what motivated the change in the representation and is there any advantage in the modern representation over the older one? I prefer the one with $\nu $ to the one with the function $G, $ but in the end I can prove the same facts with either. So, what prompted this change over time? I'd like to think that there is more than just cosmetics to it....

Thank you

Maurice